# How to push images with appium on AWS device farm devices

Tags: amazon-web-services, appium, appium-android, appium-ios, aws-device-farm

I've created a code, that works for pushing images with appium locally on both android and iOS devices.
the images are in the appium project's /src/main/resources/images folder

```
    String basePath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String imagePath = "/src/main/resources/images/testImage.jpeg";

    File imageToPush= new File(basePath+imagePath);
```

The problem is, that when this code runs on AWS I cannot find the images ( and don't know how/where to find them).

I've tried multiple ways to construct the basePath but so far with no success

Answer (score 0):

According to Appium push file [documentation](https://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/files/push-file/), you can provide the directory to place the files.
You can try to push the file using the Android SD card directory or the iOS application data folder directory as the parameter. You can then access the files in Android SD Card or the iOS application data folder.

Alternatively, you can also use the Add Extra Data feature to add the images in form of a zip file when you schedule a run on the console or you provide a extraDataPackageArn in the [schedule-run](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/schedule-run.html) CLI command. extraDataPackageArn is generated from the [create-upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/create-upload.html) CLI command. In this case, you can use create-upload CLI command on the images in form of a zip file you want to push to the device to get the extraDataPackageArn.

You can then access the extra data in Android SD card or the iOS application data folder according to https://aws.amazon.com/device-farm/faqs/,

> Q: I’d like to supply media or other data for my app to consume. How do I do that?
> You can provide a .zip archive up to 4 GB in size. On Android, it will be extracted to the root of external memory; on iOS, to your app’s sandbox.
> For Android expansion files (OBB), we will automatically place the file into the location appropriate to the OS version.

Comment: Hey!
Thank you for your answer!
For android, all is "fine" ( the push does not work though, whatever push directory you add, it won't show up) but for android, the AWS ExtraData works. ( images from extradata shown in image picker ).
For iOS, the Push method goes on timeout, and for push you don't need to add any folder parameter.
For iOS, Extra Data probably "works" but I cannot use images in the app data, since I need them to be in the photo picker ( and to access programatically the img from app data I still need to push, which again, is not working.